# Materializecss - Vertical align form/collection

Tags: html, css, css-position, materialize

I would like to vertical align my collection (form) like this :
[image: What I want]

I tried to use *valign-wrapper* and *valign*, but it's not working :
[image]
Code :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<h3 class="col s12">Matériel</h3>
<div class="col s12 l6">
<img src="img/camera.png" alt="Canon EOS 700D" class="responsive-img" data-caption="CANON EOS 700D" />
</div>
<div class="col s12 l6 valign-wrapper">
<ul class="collection with-header">
<li class="collection-header"><h4>Canon EOS 700D</h4></li>
<li class="collection-item">Résolution de capteur : 18.5Mégapixels</li>
<li class="collection-item">Ecran tactile 7.7"</li>
<li class="collection-item">Objectif 18-55 Mm IS STM 18 Mpix</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is someone have an idea about how to do this ?

*PS1 : I'm using Materializecss*

*PS2 : Sorry for my bad english !*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/acburst/pen/jyreOe)

Make sure when you are using the `valign-wrapper` helper you put it on the wrapping container. So if you want to center your collection to the height of the image, you would add the class to the div containing both those elements. In this codepen I simplified your structure a bit and added the `valign-wrapper` to the row.

Also, in general, you want to make sure your `col` divs are direct children of your `row` divs.

```
<div class="row container valign-wrapper">
  <div class="col s12 l6">
    <h3>Matériel</h3>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x800" alt="Canon EOS 700D" class="responsive-img" data-caption="CANON EOS 700D" />
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 l6">
    <ul class="collection with-header">
      <li class="collection-header"><h4>Canon EOS 700D</h4></li>
      <li class="collection-item">Résolution de capteur : 18.5Mégapixels</li>
      <li class="collection-item">Ecran tactile 7.7"</li>
      <li class="collection-item">Objectif 18-55 Mm IS STM 18 Mpix</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it works !
But .. I've got an issue. When i'm on mobile, the grid is not working. I mean, the photo is not above the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="vertical-align:middle"` to your image.

```
<img src="img/camera.png" style="vertical-align:middle" alt="Canon EOS 700D" class="responsive-img" data-caption="CANON EOS 700D" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/wadie/pen/PWzaxy)

```html
 <div class="row">
<div class="col s6 offset-s6 valign-wrapper collection">
<ul class="with-header">
<li class="collection-header"><h4>Canon EOS 700D</h4></li>
<li class="collection-item">Résolution de capteur : 18.5Mégapixels</li>
<li class="collection-item">Ecran tactile 7.7"</li>
<li class="collection-item">Objectif 18-55 Mm IS STM 18 Mpix</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Try that code. it moves your container to the right and sets the vertical length to 6 columns using col `col s6 offset-s6`

You can read more about it here under [Offsets](http://materializecss.com/grid.html)